# How does the Form.Modal property changes when using button in a form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm using 2 forms in an application in which, clicking button in form1 opens form2.  While opening form2, the `Modal` property of form2 is FALSE. But, once on clicking the button in form2, the value of this property is set to TRUE. I have used the below code in the application.

**Form1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
bool isModal = f2.Modal;
f2.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Form2**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool isModal = this.Modal;
}
```

Kindly share your ideas on how this is updated?

Thanks,

Sindhu

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.modal?view=netframework-4.7.2) state:

> Gets a value indicating whether this form is displayed modally.

The key word here is **is**.

Let's look at your code:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
bool isModal = f2.Modal;
f2.ShowDialog();
```

The question you need to ask is "in that second line, is the form **at that time** shown modally?"

The answer is clearly **No**, since it is only shown modally on the **third** line. *If you think logically, this makes perfect sense. The form **doesn't know** whether you are going to call `Show` or `ShowDialog` - so `Modal` can't tell you about the future - it can only tell you about the current state of affairs.*

Thus, on the second line, `Modal` must (according to the docs) return `false`.

OK, so why is it true in here?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool isModal = this.Modal;
}
```

Well, based on the docs we need to ask ourselves whether `this` is currently displayed modally when the button is clicked. Yes **at that time** it is, so it **must** (according to the docs) return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

While it may appear to have something to do with the buttons, it does not. It has to do with `ShowDialog();` method.

If you check before `f2.ShowDialog();`, the `Modal` will be false. Check after and it will be true.

This `f2.ShowDialog();` is what sets the property to true.

You may use `f2.Show()` and it will stay false in this case for obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

As @CodingYoshi said, the method that is setting the `Form.Modal` to true is `Form.ShowDialog()`. This is why `f2.Modal` is false, because it is called before `f2.ShowDialog()`.
The problem is checking the `f2.Modal` after calling `f2.ShowDialog`. The problem is that you cannot execute any further code lines in the code block after calling `f2.ShowDialog()`. Thus, there is no way to call `f2.Modal`.
The best way to see this difference to check `Modal` first in your constructor and then check it again in the `Form.Load` event. The constructor is called before `ShowDialog` is called, but `Form.Load` and `Button.clicked` are called after `ShowDialog` is called. Thus, you have different values for the `Modal` property.
Here the constructor of `Form2`:

```
Sub New ()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Console.WriteLine(Me.Modal) ' is always false
End Sub
```

And then `Form.Loading` event of `Form2`:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Console.WriteLine(Me.Modal) ' will return true if object is called via ShowDialog()
End Sub
```